# How to manually obtain the same output as model.predict() in keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce, via Numpy, the output that I would obtain using Keras' `model.predict()`. My keras model layers are the following:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param    
=================================================================
main_input (InputLayer)      (None, 10, 76)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
masking (Masking)            (None, 10, 76)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
rnn (SimpleRNN)              [(None, 64), (None, 64)]  9024      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
denseoutput (Dense)          (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 13,249
Trainable params: 13,249
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The second output of the SimpleRNN layer is the state returned by `return_state=True`.

I have tried 2 different approaches. First, I computed **WXt + Us + b**, where **W** is the kernel, **Xt** is the input, **U** is the recurrent kernel, **s** is the state obtained via `return_state=True`, and **b** is the bias. This returned a similar output to the one obtained with `predict()` (function `mult_1`).

After that, I tried a similar approach with function `mult_2`, but obtained worse results than with `mult_1`.

```
def mult_1(X):
    X = ma.masked_values(X, -99)
    s = (model.predict(X)[1])

    W = (model.get_weights()[0])
    U = (model.get_weights()[1])
    b = (model.get_weights()[2])

    Wx = np.dot(X[:,-1,:], W)
    Us = np.dot(s,U)

    output = Wx + Us + b

    return np.tanh(output)

def mult2(X):
    max_habitantes = X.shape[1]
    i = 0
    s_0 = np.ones((X.shape[0], 64)) # initial state
    X = ma.masked_values(X, -99)

    while i < 10:
        Xt = X[:,i,:]
        if i == 0:
            s = s_0
        else:
            s = output

        W = (model.get_weights()[0])
        U = (model.get_weights()[1])
        b = (model.get_weights()[2])

        Wx = np.dot(Xt, W)
        Us = np.dot(s,U)

        output = np.tanh(Wx + Us +b)
        i = i+1

    return output
```

Predictions are somewhat off, although not that different from those of `predict()`. Am I doing some multiplications wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array of zeros as the initial state for the rnn in mult_2.
The following two snippets of code will gives you the same result:

```
x = np.random.rand(1,10,76)
```

Using Keras model.predict()

```
inputs = Input(shape=(10,76), dtype=np.float32)
_, state = SimpleRNN(units=64, return_state=True)(inputs)
out_drop = Dropout(0.2)(state)
out_d1 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')(out_drop)
out = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(out_d1)

model = Model(inputs, out)
```

`In [1]: model.predict(x)
Out[1]: array([[-0.82426485]]`

Using a numpy function for prediction:

```
def rnn_pred(X):
    """
    Same as your mult_2 func. but with zero init. for rnn initial state
    """
    W = (model.get_weights()[0])
    U = (model.get_weights()[1])
    b = (model.get_weights()[2])

    max_habitantes = X.shape[1]
    i = 0
    s_0 = np.zeros((X.shape[0], 64)) # initial state

    while i < 10:
        Xt = X[:,i,:]
        if i == 0:
            s = s_0
        else:
            s = output

        Wx = np.dot(Xt, W)
        Us = np.dot(s,U)

        output = np.tanh(Wx+Us+b)
        i = i+1

    return output

def dense_pred(rnn_out):
    U_d1 = (model.get_weights()[3]) # dense64 weights
    b_d1 = (model.get_weights()[4]) # dense64 bias
    U_d2 = (model.get_weights()[5]) # dense1 weights
    b_d2 = (model.get_weights()[6]) # dense1 bias

    out1 = np.dot(rnn_out, U_d1) + b_d1
    out1 = np.tanh(out1)
    out2 = np.dot(out1, U_d2) + b_d2
    out2 = np.tanh(out2)
    return out2
```

`In [2]: dense_pred(rnn_pred(x))
Out[2]: array([[-0.82426485]])`

Comment: This was one of the problems. The main problem was that I was using -99 as mask value instead of 0 and keras changes those values to 0 when predicting. It worked when I changed the -99's to 0's.